# When trying to compile Python does not see Windows SDK in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, winapi, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a program `python -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py`
At the output `FATAL: Error, the Windows SDK must be installed in Visual Studio.`
However, **VS installer** detect

`Package SDK for CRT for Windows`

`Package SDK for .NET Famework 4.7.2`

`Package SDK for Windows 10 (10.0.15063.0)  for UWP. C++`

`Package SDK for Windows 10 (10.0.15063.0) for UWP. C#, VB, JS`

Comment: Are you running this from a *Developer Command Prompt*?

Comment: These packages are not the Windows SDK. The Windows SDK is this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ you can install it separately or use Visual Studio's installer, "Individual Components", and check one or all of "Windows 10 SDK" or "Windows 11 SDK" in the proposed list

Comment: @IInspectable, No, before that I ran it from cmd (+ environment created by conda), but now I tried it and got an error `FATAL: Error, scons failed to create the expected file 'nefilestrict'.`

Comment: @SimonMourier I have installed Windows SDK (10.0.10586.0). And if I understand correctly, this is what I need? But so far the error has not changed.

Comment: It seems the challenge here is to combine two environments. I'm guessing you could start a command prompt initialized with a conda environment, and then set up the VS environment from there. The latter can be done by executing *VsDevCmd.bat* that's located under your Visual Studio installation in the *Common7\Tools* directory.

Comment: This Windows SDK is quite old. Install the latest to be sure. Not sure what you want to do with `-onefilestrict`. This parameter also creates the "failed to create the expected file 'nefilestrict'" error for me. Without it, the compilation works fine (using regular python 3.10).

Comment: @IInspectable
input - `(environment)....\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools>python -m nuitka -onefilestrict test.py`  output- `FATAL: Error, the Windows SDK must be installed in Visual Studio`

Comment: Well, yes, the environment doesn't just materialize itself out of thin air purely by virtue of navigating to a filesystem directory. You'll want to actually run *VsDevCmd.bat*, too. That'll set up the environment variables that other tooling seems to rely on.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Reinstalled VS, installed a newer version of the SDK. And now I have the same mistake as you `FATAL: Error, scons failed to create the expected file 'nefilestrict'.`I need to compile a file for another device that doesn't have python installed. Can you suggest other possible options besides `-onefilestrict`? of the complications, I need to add the pandas and tk libraries

Comment: What is this "-onefilestrict" thing? Obviously it doesn't work, what do you think it should do?

Comment: Nuitka seems to follow the popular convention of introducing options with two dashes, with a single dash being reserved for short alternatives. The option is thus `--onefilestrict`. Passing `-onefilestrict` seems to instead get interpreted as `-o` with the argument `nefilestrict`.